# python 3.x progressbar tkinter backwards?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I am using python 3.4, tkinter and I want to use progrssbar to simulate a syringe, I mean the liquid inside of the syringe would be the progressbar

normally this progressbar in tkinter python 3.4 goes in horizontal or vertical position, I want it vertical, I know that it start to fill the bar from the bottom to the top, which is right the syringe is getting liquid

but my question is how can I put it backwards? I mean the progressbar instead of filling the syringe
will be emptying the syringe

I am using

```
BarVolVal_1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='horizontal', length=100, mode='determinate')
BarVolVal_1.place(x=80,y=80)
BarVolVal_1.start(50)
```

help I just want to fill and empty the bar

Comment: Can you provide complete example? what is mGui? some dummy version of code that we could just copy and paste to run would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Progressbar.start()`, you have no control over the step size, it defaults to 1.
So instead of using `Progressbar.start()`, you'll have to make your own loop to call `Progressbar.step(stepsize)`. That way, you can make the step size negative to reverse the direction of the step.

In the example below, I've made a `step` function which is called every 50ms and, depending on the direction `dir`, sets a step of 1 or -1 (the value of `dir`). Then after 3 seconds `change_dir` is called, which changes the direction of the step to -1 so the progressbar 'empties'. From then, the direction is changed every 2 seconds.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def step():
    BarVolVal_1.step(dir)
    mGui.after(50, step)

def change_dir():
    global dir
    dir *= -1
    mGui.after(2000, change_dir)

mGui = tk.Tk()
dir = 1

BarVolVal_1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='horizontal', length=100, mode='determinate')
BarVolVal_1.pack()

step()
mGui.after(3000, change_dir)

mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: I try your code but look at this error                           Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop\BBB Project\try2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm on 2.7 and I didn't pay attention to you mentioning using Python 3. I'll update the import statements.

Comment: I have one more question, filling the progress bar is fine, but I want to empty the progress bar, so I first assign it a value = 100, can I empty it, by calling the function step once it is with a value of 100 and going down? like dir -1 only?

Comment: Yeah, the main idea I wanted to tell you is that you should use `Progressbar.step(stepsize)` with a negative step size to empty the progressbar. And because this sets only one step, you should use an `after` call to itself to keep stepping down. The direction change is ofcourse something you should control elsewhere in your program, not just every 2 seconds. But setting it to 100 and just setting negative steps should work perfectly as a way of emptying the progressbar, have you tried it?

Comment: yeap, it is not working, I have uploaded the code in my question, it is after EDITED, look at it

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a new question. Two questions in one doesn't make anything clearer.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks for your help, but that code is for 2.7,

the code for 3.4 is this one and it is working

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def step():
    BarVolVal_1.step(dir)
    mGui.after(50, step)
def change_dir():
    global dir
    dir *= -1
    mGui.after(2000, change_dir)
mGui = tk.Tk()
dir = 1
BarVolVal_1 = ttk.Progressbar(mGui, orient='vertical', length=100, mode='determinate')
BarVolVal_1.pack()
step()
mGui.after(3000, change_dir)
mGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can I ask you why you just unaccepted my answer and then accepted you own answer? Your answer is just the answer I wrote, but with the import statements updated for python 3.4, which I later also updated in my answer. Your answer doesn't give any new or extra information, so I'm surprised to see you unaccepted my answer and accepted your own.

Comment: ups, sorry my mistake, I will fix it